# How to end my JQuery/Javascript game?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the script from my program. It is a higher/lower game. There are much more elements in my array then those 3 but I didn't want that the code was too long for here so.. My problem is: `aantalPogingen` starts at 5, every time he answers wrong, this will drop by 1 and when he reaches 0 I want that my game stops en give him a notification that it is game over.

```
var randomNummer = Math.floor((Math.random() * kaartenHart.length));
var punten = 0;
var aantalPogingen = 5;
var kaartenHart = ["img/heart1.png", "img/heart2.png", "img/heart3.jpg"];

function drawKaart() {
  $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[randomNummer]);
}

function hogereKaart() {
  var hoger = Math.floor((Math.random() * kaartenHart.length));
  $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[hoger]);
  if (hoger >= randomNummer) {
    punten++;
    $("#score").html("SCORE : " + punten);
  } else {
    aantalPogingen--;
    $("#pogingen").html("Number of wrong guesses left : " + aantalPogingen);
  }

  randomNummer = hoger;
  $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[hoger]);
}

function lagereKaart() {
  var lager = Math.floor((Math.random() * kaartenHart.length));
  $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[lager]);
  if (lager <= randomNummer) {
    punten++;
    $("#score").html("SCORE : " + punten);
  } else {
    aantalPogingen--;
    $("#pogingen").html("Number of wrong guesses left : " + aantalPogingen);
  }
  randomNummer = lager;
  $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[lager]);
}


$(document).ready(drawKaart);
```

Comment: from where these `hogereKaart()` and `lagereKaart()` are getting called?

Comment: In my HTML with a button onclick="hogereKaart()"

Comment: please don't remove all of question to say thanks

Comment: But for school we have to upload our project via Turnitin but I'm afraid that the program will say I duplicated a lot of code of internet just because I posted almost all my code here to ask a question..

Comment: @SenneMachtelinckx I'm sure you wont get wrong for plagiarizing your own code

Answer (score 2):

Here's my two cents... It't not tested, but you can get the idea of introducing few new functions to help you optimize and manage code ;)

```
var randomNummer = Math.floor((Math.random() * kaartenHart.length));
var punten = 0;
var aantalPogingen = 5;
var kaartenHart = ["img/heart1.png","img/heart2.png", "img/heart3.jpg"];

function drawKaart() {
    $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[randomNummer]);
}

function hogereKaart() {
   if(isGameOver()){
        alerGameOver();
    } else {
        var hoger = Math.floor((Math.random() * kaartenHart.length)); 
        $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[hoger]); 
        if (hoger >= randomNummer){
             punten++; 
             $("#score").html("SCORE : " + punten);
         }
         else{
             setRemainingTries(aantalPogingen--); 
         }

         randomNummer = hoger;
         $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[hoger]);
     }
}

function lagereKaart() {
    if(isGameOver()){
        alerGameOver();
    } else {
        var lager = Math.floor((Math.random() * kaartenHart.length)); 
        $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[lager]); 
        if (lager <= randomNummer){
            punten++; 
            $("#score").html("SCORE : " + punten);
        }
        else{
            setRemainingTries(aantalPogingen--);
        }
        randomNummer = lager;
        $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[lager]);
    }
}


function alerGameOver(){
    alert('Game Over');
}

function isGameOver(){
    if(aantalPogingen == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function setRemainingTries(newPoints){
    if(isGameOver())
        alertGameOver();
    else {
        aantalPogingen = newPoints;
        $("#pogingen").html("Number of wrong guesses left : " + aantalPogingen);
    }     
}

$(document).ready(drawKaart);
```

Comment: Yes I added some functions like you did and I got what I wanted :)

Comment: And don't forget to upvote and accept helpful answers if they solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this:

```
function hogereKaart() {
        if(aantalPogingen > 0){ //if aantalPogingen is greater than 0 then only allow user to perform the operation
           var hoger = Math.floor((Math.random() * kaartenHart.length)); 
           $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[hoger]); 
           if (hoger >= randomNummer){
                punten++; 
                $("#score").html("SCORE : " + punten);
            }
            else{
                aantalPogingen--; 
                if(aantalPogingen == 0) //checking it to 0
                {
                    alert("Your game is over");
                }
                else{
                    $("#pogingen").html("Number of wrong guesses left : " + aantalPogingen);
                }   
            }

             randomNummer = hoger;
             $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[hoger]);
        }
   }

    function lagereKaart() {
        if(aantalPogingen > 0){ //if aantalPogingen is greater than 0 then only allow user to perform the operation
            var lager = Math.floor((Math.random() * kaartenHart.length)); 
            $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[lager]); 
            if (lager <= randomNummer){
                punten++; 
                $("#score").html("SCORE : " + punten);
            }
            else{
                aantalPogingen--;
                if(aantalPogingen == 0) //checking it to 0
                {
                    alert("Your game is over");
                }
                else{
                    $("#pogingen").html("Number of wrong guesses left : " + aantalPogingen);
                }
            }
            randomNummer = lager;
            $('#afbeeldingKaart').attr('src', kaartenHart[lager]);
        }
    }
```

I have added the `if` conditions to check value of `aantalPogingen` with zero. If its greater than 0 then only calculation will happen on button `click`. Otherwise button `click` will not change anything. Also if `aantalPogingen == 0` then we will show the `alert` to end user saying their game is over. Hope this will help you.

Comment: It doesn't work perfect yet but it gave me an idea how to realize what I want, thx!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the start of both `hogereKaart()` and `lagereKaart()`

```
if(aantalPogingen ==0){
aler("game over");
return;
}
```

you might also want to do the same check in the else block before or after `aantalPogingen--` depending on when you want it to stop. Consider making it into a function to avoid repeating code.